# Is there a way to stop initalizing of the inner chrome window in electron?

Tags: electron

Iirc The Window itself is a win32 handle and the inner part of the electron app is chrome. I was wondering if there's a way to stop the action of the chromium part from executing when creating a new window?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: Want to embed a native Windows program in there. I already succeeded but the problem is that the main browser window is always on top no matter if i change the zDepth or not with winapi functions. If there was a way to remove the chromium window it'd make things 10 x easier

Comment: But having Chromium windows is the whole point of Electron... Maybe this framework is not really your use-case and you'd better be creating Win32 windows on your own? (I'm sure Node.js libraries for this task exist...)

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Yes I know that, What I was planning to do was try to have the win32  window embedded in there but there's a few things in JS i'd like to do over than in C since I already have built some logic for it  and rather not reinvent the wheel. I still plan to use Electron for multiple windows but the main window the only thing I'd like to keep is the Menubar up top.  So Just looking for an example to just resize it rather than getting rid of it completely.

Comment: I doubt that you'll be able to render another Win32 application inside the Chromium window without modifying Chromium's source code. Thus, I'm pretty sure that you'll have to use C nonetheless.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I already have it embeded inside the Electron window. The problem is even forcing the hwnd to be topmost on z-order doesn't work due to the fact that the chromium is blocking it. How do i know that the app is actually imbedded? Because when resizing the window theres a delay before the chrome app is resized and I can see my app under it.